# Twitter randomly fails to load in Chrome

Tags: twitter, google-chrome, firefox

I've been noticing over the last few weeks that when I try to load Twitter through Chrome, it will randomly decide to hang on trying to load the page, showing nothing but a blank white page, like the internet is disconnected. However loading it through Firefox works as expected, and other websites in Chrome also work as well.

Anyone else ran into this at all, and if so, do they know of a solution? Both browsers are the latest versions.

Comment: When you try to refresh the Twitter page in Chrome does it work? Have you tried clearing the cache on your browser?

Comment: Just tried both with no success.

Comment: Sometimes Twitter's cookies get in a weird state. I've found the best way to deal with this is to clear their cookies and try again. Use this Chrome Extension called [Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) to clear only the cookies for Twitter and try refreshing the page.

Comment: I am guessing this is probably because of a messy extension? or some localized setting which has messed up twitter. You might want to try disabling a few extensions.

Comment: Also try to open twitter in incognito mode (CTRL + SHIFT + N) since that won't load up any extensions

Comment: I have this problem when I have too many (well, let's say 20+) tabs open, AND multiple tabs (2? 3?) of Twitter. @thunderror is probably correct, about messy extension issues. I use  Chrome, and have experienced this problem less often since I uninstalled the extensions I didn't use much.

Comment: Well I dont' use any extensions outside of AVg. If that's it...well TS for twitter. I also use a fair number of tabs, although it does the same things well say 5 or 10. Any reports of twitter and certain extensions not playing well?

Comment: Try twitter.com/support